# How to log sql errors when restoring database from dump file

Tags: mysql, logging, error-handling, restore

Pre-apologies for any duplication here but I swear I have researched (and learned a lot in the process).

Environment is MySQL 5.5 using MYISAM table engine on Windows 7.

The job is to restore a database dumped from MySQL 4.0.  I do this from the command line (I tried using Oracle's MySQL Workbench import utility but it would fail if it encountered an error).  The restoration completes but I know there are errors getting thrown.  I want to capture those so I can make sure the restoration completes without error.

General_log doesn't seem to capture anything (and yes - it's turned on).  The other log file (local_host_name.log) doesn't seem to capture sql statement level errors at all.

Is there a method for capturing errors when restoring from the command line?  Is there a way to perhaps edit the dump file itself with throw/catch statements that would write errors to a log file?

Thanks in advance -- I'm a MS SQL guy who is brand new to MySQL.

Comment: If you are running the import via the command line, I would try to run it again with the --verbose command. This should print more information to the screen as it imports, including errors. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_verbose

Comment: I'll give that a shot -- the thing is, the dump file contains several thousand statements, and Windows command line won't display all lines.

Comment: you can redirect the output to a file using '>'. ie "mysql -u asdf -Ppass -h localhost databasename < dump.sql >errors.txt"

Comment: btw -- thanks for the help -- much appreciated -- now, from a mysql prompt using Windows command line, I run my import as follows:   mysql> source c:\path\to\dumpfile.sql     How should I encapsulate the statement with angle brackets?  I've tried several combinations and the closest I get is an error 22.

Answer (score 5):

@Rob in your prompt (cmd?) try something like:

```
mysql -u your_user your_database <c:\path\to\your_script.sql >stdout_output.txt 2>stderr_output.txt
```

there isn't angle brackets, the symbols '<' and '>' are redirect signals of command line shell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I was able to write the output to a file using the tee command.  If I try the syntax you suggest, I get a newline with this as the prompt -> but the command isn't actually executing.  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: nice that you have your problem solved. This prompt sign is strange, usually mysql prints it when some semi-comma is missed. There was any output in stderr_output.txt when you executed the command?

Answer (score 0):

I uses a bash script to restore MySQL TB database and record the output to a file like as shown below,

```
/bin/bash /home/installation/scripts/finqa_restore.sh 2>&1 | tee /home/installation/scripts/output-stat.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 pv import_test.sql | mysql -urootuser -pyourpassword the_db_name >st_out_log.txt 2>error_log.txt
```

One issue I had is that it only seems to capture one error. Perhaps the script stopped executing after the error.